# Hover on parent not overriding children background

Tags: html, css, hover, height

I want to achieve the same hover effect as this website: http://educade.org/

However, I'm encountering a few problems. For example, when I try to hover on the parent div, the previously set background colors of the children divs don't change. Only the "blank" space of the div gets highlighted.

Also, why doesn't the .box div fill the remaining height of the .videoclip div? I tried to set its height to 100%, but it overflows pretty badly.

**Parent div**

```
.videoclip{
   width:100%;
   height: 300px;
   max-height:300px;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 3px;
   border: solid 1px #e3e3e3;
}
```

**Example of the children divs (with bg color)**

```
.videoclip .box{
   background:#FFFFFF;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   display:block;
   padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Hover**

```
.videoclip:hover{
   background:#CCFF11 !important;
}
```

Here is the link to my full code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjvrEy

Is it possible to obtain the same effect with a single line of code? (applying the hover on the parent?)

Please don't post JS solutions to this issue

Comment: When you say _So I have to do it for every child,right?_, which every child are you talking about?

Comment: When you say _Can you also tell why the height of the box is not filling the remaining space_, which remaining space? ... a couple of images would do good to explain that with

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the child element after `hover` event:

```
.videoclip:hover .box
{
      background: #CCFF11;
}
```

And you won't need `important`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. So I have to do it for every child,right? I thought that applying it to the parent would be enough. Can you also tell why the height of the box is not filling the remaining space since it isn't fixed as the other two elements?

Comment: Oh yes i forgot, the height as well, give it 'auto'

Comment: If you give it auto, the .box will simply shrink if content inside is very short

Comment: Yes it will, I don't think there is another way to make the parent and the child take the same height

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the background from .videoclip.box

```
.videoclip .box{
background:#FFFFFF;
font-size: 1.1em;
display:block;
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

or add this:

```
.videoclip:hover .box{
background:#CCFF11 !important;
}
```

The !importants are not neccessary anymore then, but maybe you got other code that needs it in the future as well.

For the space that remains, check your maring-bottoms. they are at 10px and 20px, which is the remaining space.

Comment: I tried removing the margins, but it won't work. I don't want to use the absolute positioning, as other users suggest. If my videoclip is 300px high, with let's say 60 px on top, why won't the height:100% on the last child scale up to 240?